# Android BadParcelableException(Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR) only with signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, parcelable

When I run my project from debug everything works fine. However when I run it with the signed apk I generated from Android Studio (using proguard), I get the following errors when using getParcelable:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.android/mypackage.mobile.android.activities.searchActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class mypackage.android.a.d.a
```

Why does this exception happen only with my signed apk? In my proguard config file I did have to use `dontwarn android.support.v4.**` to avoid proguard errors. Is that coming back to bite me?

Comment: proguard f** up CREATOR field of your class ... you have to "tell" progroud to not tuch this filed in your class

Comment: `-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Post as answer please so I can accept, and future viewers can see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to protect `CREATOR` fields from proguard's obfuscation

add this lines to your proguard config:

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable { 
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added this to my proguard-project.txt file and it works now.

Comment: Thanks but such things should've documented by Google!

Comment: hmmm, they added such thing in defualt proguard settings: ANDROID_SDK\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt ... so if you are using proguard with gradle "in normal way" you shouldn't worry about this anymore (by normal way i mean `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), your_specific_files_go_here.pro`

Comment: For those that might be seeing a similar issue as of late, as I am, this is already included by default in all the proguard files, which are now at …\AndroidStudioProjects\<app name>\app\build\intermediates\proguard-files.  So, this answer might not be helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

For new comers, this also happens if you forget to define your CREATOR field final

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
```